# Laravel 5.1 Validation failing on correct mime/extension

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I use a request class for my validation. I have a request class that has this piece of code in there:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'attachment'  => 'mimes:png,jpg,gif'
    ];
}
```

Doing a `$request->file('attachment')->getClientMimeType()` in my controller returns `image/png`

Yet whenever I try to send a png file I'm still getting a validation error: "The attachments must be a file of type: png, jpg, gif."

I'm using a rest client called [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) to send the file to the backend via a [Multipart form](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Send_Files_as_Multipart_Form_Data)

Am I missing a step?

EDIT: I cannot use `image` as a validation rule because I eventually want to start accepting pdf/doc and other formats (`image` fails btw). So far both PDF and doc has also failed validation.

Comment: please post the form html part

Comment: I'm using a REST client called Paw to send the request to the backend. I'll update the quesition accordingly

Comment: Did you try using the `image` rule?

Comment: @user2094178 no I did not. I eventually want to start accepting pdf and doc files also but those are also failing

Comment: You say that `image` fails, which leads me to believe that the upload is not working as expected - perhaps a Paw flaw? Have you tried with another client, or even the browser?

Comment: @MikeRockett Seems like you're onto something. I just created a small form to send a file to my API endpoint and everything is working fine there. I looked at the post request in the chrome dev tools to see what was going on there but I was not able to identify something chrome is doing that Paw is not.

I've also tried sending a request with a command line tool called httpie and I'm getting the same validation fail error.

Comment: @Xecure - Any chance you can edit your question to show the two requests? There has to be something in there...

Answer (score 3):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) when you upload a file you must mention `multipart/form-data` so no characters would be encoded,which probably cause the validation fail.

Comment: My `Content-Type` header are set to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: could you post the request headers from your browser network tab? (just copy-past all the headers to make sure nothing went wrong)

Comment: @Xecure also have you made sure that the file is actually an `png` type ?

Comment: I am not using chrome but rather a REST client called Paw to make these requests. According to a cURL output that Paw gives these are my headers:  -H "Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImNTNTFyeVV6V3NlNGRNVDNiY25Pd3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMEFCSkFkVU9oRWV3c21SVW5BWjlobUQxZWRGNEIzYzNHYnJhd1ozMnRcL2FqSmxMZ3BmTWsxd2pRVGpxVFJQSEg5Wng1UkZ4UFZLVVRjUmtcL2FWWE1Bdz09IiwibWFjIjoiYmY3YTU1NzUyZDk2NDFiMmY1ZjQ2ZDY5Yjc2MmQ0NzBjNmRjZWJkNjBhMGE2N2E3NzkxZGFmMDVlMTk4NTA5MiJ9" \
 -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=A3K5XyonG4KqTbFpCmlAhtVd3S8FBB5R" \

Comment: According to www.mime.ritey.com and calling `$request->file('attachment')->getClientMimeType()` in my controller the file I'm trying to upload has a mime type of ` image/png`

Comment: @Xecure I see,have you tried to debug it using xdebug or something to tell where the validation actually fails?

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but this might help others who may stumbled on the same problem. I am using "attachments[]" as input name by the way. And I got it working using this:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
        'attachments.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,pdf'
]);
```

using the dot(.) asterisk solved my problem.

Comment: this validation rule has no impact, it'll just accept anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate why? @minhazur

Comment: I am not sure but this rule accepting everything, maybe because of .* @user

Comment: Oh I see your point, but my answer clearly said that I am using `attachment[index]` as my input name. Therefore _attachment.*_ means all indices of the "attachment" input name. Laravel docs did mention we can use this kind of validation [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays]

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem and nothing worked for me. cause the code works well locally and on my ubuntu server online it fails. What worked for me was to remove the laravel validation and use normal php validation. Sometimes simplicity is just what works.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La3uV.png)